# css custom checkbox layout

Tags: html, css, layout, checkbox

What I'm trying to accomplish is simple : change the layout of the browser checkboxes via CSS. Is it possible? Or do I need to use javascript for that? And how?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by browser checkboxes?

Comment: Checkbox layout? Please explain your question more.

Comment: Do you want to change the default 3d look of the checkbox?

Comment: Each browser has its own checkbox appearance, and I want to create a global appearance for all browsers. I've searched about this, and looks like that the only way to o it is with javascript, creating a div/span with the images an using onclick to change the value "checked" of a input type="checkbox"

Comment: If you are only shooting for Safari and Chrome [then here is a pure CSS solution](http://acidmartin.wordpress.com/2009/07/17/using-css-to-style-radiobuttons-and-checkboxes-for-safari-and-chrome/).

Comment: Here is article with no-js solution: http://moodevs.com/blog/ui/1.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind fellows, found the sollution on my own.

This script I wrote requires you to have a div/span for each checkbox, with classes "checked" and "unchecked" with the respective layouts, and a onclick event within each, with the following code (being 'b_availcheck' the id of the respective checkbox):

```
<div class="checked" onclick="javascript:change_checkbox(this, 'b_availcheck');"></div>
```

The javascript :

```
function hide_checkboxes() {
    var checkboxes = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
        if (checkboxes[i].type == 'checkbox') {
            checkboxes[i].style.visibility = 'hidden';
        }
    }
}

function change_checkbox(e, target) {
    if (e.className == 'checked') {
        document.getElementById(target).checked=false;
        e.className = 'unchecked';
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById(target).checked=true;
        e.className = 'checked';
    }
}

window.onload = hide_checkboxes;
```

This script attaches a onload event to the window so the default checkboxes get hidden on start .. Also, if javascript is disabled, the default checkboxes will work instead of this ones (many thanks to Tigraine for the tip)

Answer (score 2):

What we usually did at work is create a custom Javascript solution (a div that changes color when clicked) that changes the value of a hidden checkbox.

That way you are not constrained by CSS and if Javascript is disabled it will nicely degrade to a normal Checkbox (very important for Accessibility)

Comment: +1 progressive enhancement beats JS-only. However re-implementing form controls can still have accessibility problems; for example yoda's example code cannot be keyboard-controlled like a real checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

If you need that browser independent go for a custom control.

Have a look at

[jQuery custom styled checkbox](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-checkbox/)

If you don't want a jQuery based one then look for

[Checkboxes, Radio Buttons, Select Lists, Custom HTML Form Elements](http://ryanfait.com/resources/custom-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/)

Comment: I'd like better a sollution without JQuery. I know how to do it in that framework, but there's no need to use it in this case, since the only javascript I'll need is for this purpose.

Comment: phoenix, your second example uses too much code for something simple, and the third example actually uses jquery.

Answer (score 0):

it’s not possible with css, you have to use javascript. i really recommend [fancy-form](http://lipidity.com/fancy-form/)